PIM systems and Magento
I am looking into the topic: Catalog Data Synchronisation and Magento. Particularity, I am trying to pinpoint the possible issues people have encountered when using a PIM system. I was wondering if I could enquire about good experience with PIM systems and bad experiences just as well?
What do you think are the parameters that make Magento better with these external systems?

the catalog size
the catalog complexity
the stock requirements
anything else?

